# Grails app wont start from STS but launches from terminal

Tags: eclipse, spring, grails, spring-tool-suite

Here's what I'm getting when I try `run-app` on STS

```
2014-03-24 16:14:53,737 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodGetDeclaredAnnotations(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:935)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodGetAnnotations(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1491)
        at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:106)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:88)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:253)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:169)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-03-24 16:14:53,743 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-03-24 16:14:53,744 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
2014-03-24 16:14:53,744 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: This is a problem with SpringLoaded, the agent reloading mechanism for Spring-based apps.  There may be an incompatibility with java versions.  What version are you using in STS and on command line?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg The anomaly is that the grails app starts in debug mode.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying that you cannot start in run-mode? Or that this problem only happens in debug mode in GGTS? Your best bet is to post to the GGTS spring forum: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with SpringLoaded as @Andrew Eisenberg suggested.The problem was fixed by upgrading to `Grails 2.3.8`.