# IntelliJ IDEA failing to run a Grails 2.3.0 project

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, intellij-idea

Recently, I have imported a working Grails project from STS 3.3 into Intelj IDE . But, when I run the application, I get the following error in debug mode.

I'm on **Grails 2.3.0** and **IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1**

On **Grails console on IntelliJIDE** i see the following output:

```
/usr/share/java/jdk1.6.0_30/bin/java -Dgrails.home=/opt/grails-2.3.0 -Dbase.dir=/home/you/Projects/terra-connect -Dtools.jar=/usr/share/java/jdk1.6.0_30/lib/tools.jar -Dgroovy.starter.conf=/opt/grails-2.3.0/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -javaagent:/opt/grails-2.3.0/lib/org.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.1.3.jar -noverify -Dspringloaded=profile=grails -Didea.launcher.port=7532 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/you/Dev/idea-IU-135.480/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/grails-2.3.0/lib/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/jars/groovy-all-2.1.6.jar:/opt/grails-2.3.0/dist/grails-bootstrap-2.3.0.jar:/home/you/Dev/idea-IU-135.480/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf /opt/grails-2.3.0/conf/groovy-starter.conf run-app`
```

and a stacktrace after Running grails app, with this message:

```
2014-04-10 09:58:48,314 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodGetDeclaredAnnotations(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:935)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodGetAnnotations(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1491)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:106)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:253)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-04-10 09:58:48,319 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-04-10 09:58:48,320 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-04-10 09:58:48,320 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50341', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: provide IDEA and Grails versions pls

Comment: There is a similar issue with STS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610626/grails-app-wont-start-from-sts-but-launches-from-terminal

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel take a look at this article http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/12/grails-goodness-debugging-app-forked-mode/ maybe you missed smth

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel is your grails package stable ? have u tried it with STS or some other ?

Comment: @danielad app starts on STS on debug mode only.

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel just a monument i will answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it's not an Intellij problem. The issue is with the `-reloading` option being turned off in Grails 2.3.0. I solved my problem by upgrading to `2.3.8`.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i have got your problem , am sure your using Linux Machine. Ok , for that you need to do the following :

The root casue of this problem is the IDE need to RUN in root permisssion inorder to connect to sokcets or succsfully debug.so , you should make the following change :

Intellij requires root permissions for the built in functions to work.

```
Either start using sudo:

sudo /your/inteljdirectory/bin/idea.sh
or give all users to run in debug mode Intellij, then start as yourself:

sudo chmod -R o+rw /your/inteljdirectory/idea.sh

cd /your/inteljdirectory/bin
cd sudo ./idea.sh
```

> Keep in mInd this not directly related with your problem but ,:
>
> The location of IDEA_JDK and JDK_HOME environmental variables. They have to be placed in /etc/profile .

After defining of the environmental vars in etc/profile there are several methods to create a desktop link:

As mentioned above by Roman Shevchenko
Recommended way to integrate IDEA is to invoke Configure | Create Desktop Entry from welcome screen (or via Tools | Create Desktop Entry from main menu)

> Invoke "Make Link" on ides.sh and move "link to idea.sh" to Desktop.

DONE!! Happy coding!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer but despite running Intellij with `gksudo`, I'm getting the same error. Is is necessary to replicate your steps?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel definitely sir!

Comment: +1 for the help but it's still giving out the same error. I've updated my question by the command Intellij is trying to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `Ctrl + Alt + G` then enter `--reloading run-app` in the Command Line when the run target dialog appears. That fixed it for me!

If that works perfect then you can change the default configuration by going to Run->Edit Configuration and adding --reloading before run-app in the command line box.
Hope that helps @AlexanderSuraphel!

Comment: This worked with `2.3.11` which wasn't working for me! I'm trying debug mode now...